# Delay n seconds in javafx

Tags: multithreading, javafx, timer, delay

I am trying to add a delay before proceeding to doing the next thing. Here is my code :

```
private void startup() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                mainPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(28, 28, 28), null, null)));
                logPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(28, 28, 28), null, null)));
                startupAnimation();
            });
        }
    }, 3500);
    logMessage(Mavis.LOG_INITIALIZE);

private void startupAnimation() {
    FadeTransition ftMain = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1200), mainPane);
    ftMain.setFromValue(0);
    ftMain.setToValue(1);
    ftMain.setCycleCount(1);
    FadeTransition ftLog = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1200), logPane);
    ftLog.setFromValue(0);
    ftLog.setToValue(1);
    ftLog.setCycleCount(1);
    ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition();
    pt.getChildren().addAll(ftMain, ftLog);
    TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(800), mavisImgView);
    tt.setByX(-210);
    tt.setCycleCount(1);
    FadeTransition ftOver = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1500), overlayPane);
    ftOver.setFromValue(0);
    ftOver.setToValue(1);
    ftOver.setCycleCount(1);
    SequentialTransition seq = new SequentialTransition(pt,tt, ftOver);
    seq.play();
}

private void logMessage(String msg) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                logTxtArea.setText(msg);
                chatBalloon.setVisible(true);
            });
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

What I want to achieve is that, before logging the message the GUI has to startup for 3.5 seconds, then when the GUI is loaded, it will be logging a message. The problem is that the message is already logged along with the startup of the GUI, what seems to be the problem here? The timer used is java.util.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

For initial delay use [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) then add it at the beginning of `SequentialTransition`.

Comment: now I need a delay after startupAnimation, before    logMessage(Mavis.LOG_INITIALIZE);

Comment: then add another `PauseTransition` at the end of `SequentialTransition`. Next set event on finish:   `seq.setOnFinished(e -> logMessage(Mavis.LOG_INITIALIZE));`

Comment: @NEWBIEHERE instead of adding `(SOLVED)` to your title, click on the outlined green check next to the post that helped.